# Cocktail recipe Data Visualisation

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization, data-visualization

Generally interested in data visualisation and becoming more and more familiar with Javascripts D3 library, I found this visualisation of different cocktail recipes: [Information is beautiful - Cocktails](http://www.informationisbeautiful.net/visualizations/cocktails/)

I wonder how this was done? Is there any chance to get this done with D3js or is something like this basically a highly manual task at all?

To visualise the relative quantities of ingredients in a cocktail, one could use the stack layout. Yet, I have no idea how to deal with the different shape of cocktail glasses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, let's table the conversation of whether this is a good idea to do in `d3` (where's the **fun** in that? ) and talk about *how* we could do this in `d3`.  The below code borrows this [SVG image](http://wecanbeaoriginal.com/blog/2010/06/free-svg-download-margaritacocktail-glass/) and then applies a gradient fill to show the various parts of the cocktail.  Finally, you wrap it all up with some labels...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="d3@3.5.3" data-semver="3.5.3" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.js"></script>
  <style>
    svg{
      font: 12px sans-serif;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
  
    // our cocktail glass
    var glassPath = "m 60,350 c -4.74218,-0.7989 -7.33654,-2.5714 -7.33654,-5.0124 0,-2.4848 2.03654,-4.0776 5.21357,-4.0776 1.54746,0 3.59496,-0.4138 4.55,-0.9197 1.97894,-1.0481 9.10335,-3.4326 24.23643,-8.1118 5.775,-1.7856 11.4,-3.6018 12.5,-4.0358 1.1,-0.434 4.3253,-1.3074 7.16733,-1.9408 5.71266,-1.2732 7.4813,-2.8015 9.21631,-7.9635 0.64176,-1.9094 2.38458,-4.7427 3.87294,-6.2962 l 2.70609,-2.8245 -0.2841,-27.7039 c -0.15625,-15.2371 -0.68535,-33.7788 -1.17577,-41.2038 -0.49042,-7.425 -1.20657,-21.825 -1.59145,-32 -0.94914,-25.0923 -1.70127,-27.1843 -15.45994,-43 -3.11003,-3.575 -7.5473,-9.326 -9.8606,-12.7799 -4.25363,-6.3511 -14.06748,-25.7631 -14.0826,-27.8558 -0.005,-0.6246 -0.68044,-2.4246 -1.50205,-4 -0.82161,-1.57534 -1.49661,-3.90636 -1.5,-5.18002 -0.003,-1.27366 -0.46743,-3.17763 -1.0312,-4.23105 -0.56377,-1.05341 -1.45572,-4.96133 -1.98212,-8.68426 -0.88933,-6.28986 -2.39223,-14.81377 -3.51606,-19.94188 -0.65359,-2.98237 -5.07693,-8.04956 -9.42012,-10.7913 -3.31741,-2.09419 -6.56863,-3.11638 -17.55666,-5.51985 -13.14833,-2.87601 -26.01544,-13.25971 -31.54627,-25.45769 -3.44329,-7.59403 -6.63083,-22.12177 -6.86935,-31.30823 l -0.0844,-3.25 131,0 131,0 -0.0844,3.25 c -0.23852,9.18646 -3.42606,23.7142 -6.86935,31.30823 -5.53083,12.19798 -18.39794,22.58168 -31.54627,25.45769 -10.98803,2.40347 -14.23925,3.42566 -17.55666,5.51985 -4.34319,2.74174 -8.76653,7.80893 -9.42012,10.7913 -1.12383,5.12811 -2.62673,13.65202 -3.51606,19.94188 -0.5264,3.72293 -1.41835,7.63085 -1.98212,8.68426 -0.56377,1.05342 -1.02781,2.95739 -1.0312,4.23105 -0.003,1.27366 -0.67839,3.60468 -1.5,5.18002 -0.82161,1.5754 -1.49753,3.3754 -1.50205,4 -0.0151,2.0927 -9.82897,21.5047 -14.0826,27.8558 -2.3133,3.4539 -6.75057,9.2049 -9.8606,12.7799 -13.75867,15.8157 -14.5108,17.9077 -15.45994,43 -0.38488,10.175 -1.10103,24.575 -1.59145,32 -0.49042,7.425 -1.01952,25.9667 -1.17577,41.2038 l -0.2841,27.7039 2.70609,2.8245 c 1.48836,1.5535 3.23118,4.3868 3.87294,6.2962 1.73501,5.162 3.50365,6.6903 9.21631,7.9635 2.84203,0.6334 6.06733,1.5068 7.16733,1.9408 1.1,0.434 6.725,2.2502 12.5,4.0358 15.13308,4.6792 22.25749,7.0637 24.23643,8.1118 0.95504,0.5059 3.00254,0.9197 4.55,0.9197 5.51258,0 7.05386,4.7477 2.50848,7.727 -2.52335,1.6539 -7.71319,1.7828 -77.25,1.9187 -40.9997,0.08 -76.41846,-0.17 -78.70837,-0.5557 z"
    
    // some drinks to show
    var data = [
      {
        drink: "Angel Face",
        parts: [
          { 
            unit: 3,
            name: "Calvados"
          },{ 
            unit: 3,
            name: "Apricot Brandy"
          },{ 
            unit: 3,
            name: "Gin"
          }
        ]
      }, {
        drink: "Aviation",
        parts: [
          { 
            unit: 1.5,
            name: "Maraschino"
          },{ 
            unit: 1.5,
            name: "Lemon Juice"
          },{ 
            unit: 4.5,
            name: "Gin"
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
    
    // 47 percent of our glass is where the liquid is
    var colorPercent = 47,
      // 3 percent is the empty spot on top
      // 50 percent is the stem
      startPercent = 50 - colorPercent,
      // width and height of the glass
      drinkWidth = 265,
      drinkHeight = 350,
      colors = d3.scale.category10();

    // calculate percentages...
    data.forEach(function(d0){
      var totPercent = startPercent,
          total = d3.sum(d0.parts, function(d1){ return d1.unit; });
      d0.gradient = [];
      d0.parts.forEach(function(d1){
        d1.startPercent = totPercent;
        d0.gradient.push({
          percent: totPercent,
          color: colors(d1.name)
        });
        totPercent += ((d1.unit / total) * colorPercent);
        d1.endPercent = totPercent;
        d0.gradient.push({
          percent: totPercent,
          color: colors(d1.name)
        });
      });
    });
    
    var svg = d3.select('body')
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', (drinkWidth * data.length) + 5)
      .attr('height', drinkHeight + 20);
      

    // a g for each glass;
    var glass = svg.selectAll('.drink')
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append('g')
      .attr('class', 'drink')
      .attr('transform', function(d,i){
        return 'translate(' + (drinkWidth * i) + ',0)';
      })
    
    // the glass
    glass
      .append('path')
      .attr('d', glassPath)
      .style('stroke', 'black')
      .style('fill', function(d,i){
        return 'url(#grad' + i + ')';
      });
      
    // text labels of drink
    glass
      .append("text")
      .attr("x", drinkWidth / 2)
      .attr("y", drinkHeight)
      .text(function(d){
        return d.drink;
      })
      .attr("dy", "1em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle")
      .style("font-size", "16");
      
    // text labels of drink parts
    glass.selectAll('.label')
      .data(function(d){
        return d.parts;
      })
      .enter()
      .append('text')
      .attr('class', 'label')
      .text(function(d){
        return d.unit + " " + d.name;
      })
      .style("fill", "black")
      .attr("x", drinkWidth / 2)
      .attr("y", function(d){
        return (((d.startPercent + d.endPercent) / 2) / 100) * drinkHeight;
      })
      .attr("dy", "1em")
      .style("text-anchor", "middle");
      
    // our gradients
    var grad = svg.append('defs')
      .selectAll('linearGradient')
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append('linearGradient')
      .attr('id', function(d,i){
        return "grad" + i;
      })
      .attr('x1', '0%')
      .attr('x2', '0%')
      .attr('y1', '0%')
      .attr('y2', '100%');
      
    // no liquid top of glass
    grad.append("stop")
      .attr("offset", "0%")
      .style("stop-color", "white");
      
    grad.append("stop")
      .attr("offset", startPercent + "%")
      .style("stop-color", "white");
    
    var e = grad.selectAll('.color')
      .data(function(d){
        return d.gradient
      })
      .enter();

    e.append("stop")
      .attr('id', function(d,i){
        return 'stop' + 1;
      })
      .attr("offset", function(d){
        return d.percent + '%';
      })
      .style("stop-color", function(d){
        return d.color;
      });

    // stem of glass
    grad.append("stop")
      .attr("offset", "50%")
      .style("stop-color", "black");
    
    grad.append("stop")
      .attr("offset", "100%")
      .style("stop-color", "black");
    
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Doing something like this in D3 is like hammering a board of nails with your smartphone - eventually you will get the job done, but you've picked the wrong tool to do this.

Like a smartphone, D3 has a lot of possibilities, but this task requires a lot of visual details that D3 is not tuned to accomplish.

You see, graphic editor tools are there for a reason - they give you the possibility to create composite images with great fonts, colors, layers and much more. The Cocktails infographic is a perfect fit for such a task - you can easily add small mint leaves, peach bitters and blackberries on your canvas in a snap.

On the other hand, go make even a simple barchart in a graphic editor. I've done this (don't ask me why) and I had to do some math in order to draw the correct proportions of bars.

There are tools for each type of job you need to accomplish. The important thing is to know how to choose the right one. D3 stands for Data Driven Documents - and this tells everything. Whenever you have DATA, choose D3.

You can tell that in the cocktails infographic there is data. Indeed. But I would like to tell you about a simple, yet very important concept in data visualization: the signal-to-noise ratio (check [this](http://www.presentationzen.com/presentationzen/2007/03/signaltonoise_r.html) article that explains the concept), that is somehow like a quality metric of how much noise is there in your data (do not confuse design with noise). While answering this, I came up with *signal-to-design ratio*©. (I don't have this backed up by any research, so bear with me), that tells you how much design you need **besides** data. In cocktails infographic, you have much more design than data - therefore D3 doesn't fit for this task.

**As a conclusion:** each task is suited best for a specific tool, designed to accomplish it. Learn to choose the right tools for your tasks - this will save you at least your time.

Comment: We call your "signal-to-design ratio" the data-ink ratio, a Tufte's concept:
http://www.infovis-wiki.net/index.php/Data-Ink_Ratio

Comment: I think Tufte's data-ink ratio is the "signal-to-noise" ratio rather that signal-to-design ratio. In his book, "The Visual Display of Quantitative Information", he talks about charts and other visuals that display A LOT of data. In a 2 dimensional plane, he manages to display several features of the data. My point with the "signal-to-design" ratio was that some visuals have less data, but if you'll display only that data (percentage of each ingredient), it won't have the same effect as those fancy glasses and shots.

Comment: Hi iulian, thank you very much for your answer. I think you are absolutely right with you answer. D3 might not be the ideal tool for this purpose. Especially when it comes to the small details, like the fruit bits and so on. Thus, I was somehow but positively surprised by Marks answer, which is really more than I expected what D3 could do. Again, thank you very much.